# How to handle a very long vector in Pytorch?

Tags: vector, pytorch, autoencoder, loss

Now there is a problem. I have a noise reduction encoder for data denoising. Now my input is a vector of length 20,000 and my model structure is as follows.

```
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim = None):
    super().__init__()
    if output_dim is None:
        output_dim = input_dim

    self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 1024),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(1024,512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(512,256),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(256,512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(512,1024),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(1024,input_dim)
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.fc(x)
    return out
```

I add noise to the original data, and the added noise follows a standard normal distribution. The purpose of the model is to predict the added noise. The loss function is the L2 loss between the added noise and the predicted noise. However, during the training process, no matter how I adjust the learning rate or increase the model complexity, my loss has been consistently high, and the predicted noise is very small, obviously far from the added noise, and after checking the gradient, I found that the gradient is close to 0. When I reduce the length of this input vector to 1,000, the loss can be reduced, but the convergence value is not ideal. How can I solve the problem I encountered?

I have already tried increasing the complexity of the model, but it didn't help reduce my loss. I hope there is a way to make my loss decrease continuously during training and eventually converge to a desirable value.

Comment: I am not sure what is the question here. The title seems to be different from the question in the body. Is the problem that the model performs significantly worse when the vector dimension is too high?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your problem correctly, the root problem is that your gradient is vanishing. [Skip connections can help with the vanishing gradient problem](https://theaisummer.com/skip-connections/). To create skip connections, simply add (as in arithmetic) the results of earlier layers to later layers.

This is your architecture implemented with scheme B, but it may be worth experimenting with other skip connection schemes.

[image: skip connection schemes]

```py
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim = None):
    super().__init__()
    if output_dim is None:
        output_dim = input_dim

    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 1024),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
            nn.GELU(),
    )
    
    self.fc2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1024,512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.GELU(),
    )

    self.fc3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512,256),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            nn.GELU(),
    )

    self.fc4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(256,512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.GELU(),
    )

    self.fc5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512,1024),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
            nn.GELU(),
    )

    self.fc6 = nn.Linear(1024,input_dim)

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.fc1(x)
    out = self.fc2(out) + out
    out = self.fc3(out) + out
    out = self.fc4(out) + out
    out = self.fc5(out) + out
    out = self.fc6(out)
    return out
```